# Need help achieve a file viewing script

Tags: bash

I need help to make a bash script file viewing.

I I have files that I get all the 30 minute, I automatic ranges in folders named by date
ex:

```
/Data/ operator/20160515/EXPLOIT/
/Data/ operator/20160516/EXPLOIT/
/Data/ operator/20160517/EXPLOIT/

/Data/operator/20160518/PROD/
/Data/operator/20160518/PROD/
/Data/operator/20160518/PROD/
```

each folder contains files of a day in the format "datehour-toto.tz" I would like in a script type eg "send.sh 201605151530 201605171300" automatically list all the files between these two dates in a ls example ?

I do not know where to start because it made me tough the air achieve? because it takes every file checker in the 2 dates and times

I found something that might be a good start, but I do not know how to tell the EXPLOIT subdirectory

```
directory="data/"
find ${directory} -type f | awk -vSTART=$1 -vSTOP=$2 '
{
t = substr($0, length("'${directory}'")+10, 12)
}
t > START && t < STOP {
print
}'


./send.sh 201508190810 201508190900
 data/20150819/201508190821-toto.tz
 data/20150819/201508190823-toto.tz
 data/20150819/201508190820-toto.tz
 data/20150819/201508190822-toto.tz
```

if anyone could help me , I do not speak much English .

Comment: change second line to: `find ${directory} -path '*/EXPLOIT/*" -type f | awk ...`

Comment: Hello and Mercu for your help, I try to change the script as you told me, but the process is very long, it happened 20 minutes and I have not had any result, there must be an error no ? `find ${repertoire} -path '*/EXPLOIT/*' -type f | awk -vSTART=$1 -vSTOP=$2 '
{
   t = substr($0, length("'${repertoire}'")+10, 12)
}
t > START && t < STOP {
   print
}'
`

Answer (score 0):

here is a faster way:

```
find data -maxdepth 2 -type d -name EXPLOIT |
  awk -v start=$1 -v end=$3 -F/ '$2>=start && $2<=end' |
  xargs -I{} find "{}" -type f |
  awk -v start=$1$2 -v end=$3$4 -F/ '$4>=start && $4<=end'
```

usage:

```
./send.sh 20160515 1530 20160517 1300
```

there is also a fast and easy way to do this on the command line instead of in a script:

```
find data/2016051*/EXPLOIT -type f | awk -F/ '$4>=201605151530 && $4<=201605171300'
```

how does this work?

```
find data/2016051*/EXPLOIT
```

finds directories named EXPLOIT inside of directories named 2016051*, so: 20160510 - 20160519. it saves time by not considering other ones. this way is even faster:

```
find data/2016051[567]/EXPLOIT
```

it finds inside of directories 20160515, 20160516, 20160517.

if you wanted to search from 20160529 - 20160601, try:

```
find data/20160*/EXPLOIT
```

or, faster:

```
find data/20160[56]*/EXPLOIT
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your help, it's really cool when I did my test I   have this syntax error  `awk: cmd. line:1: {t=strtonum($5); t>=start && t<=end && print}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                        ^ syntax error`

Comment: there was a bug. this is fixed and tested now.

Comment: you're welcome :) sorry about the previous bug. ps: if you're happy with this answer, please mark it as accepted.